# Running a script on one spreadsheet to change values on another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Looking to run a script on spreadsheet A and change values on spreadsheet B.  If I was running the script within spreadsheet B the following works:

```
function clear() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
      spreadsheet.getRange('Responses!C8:E50').setValue('');
}
```

How do I change the above script to do the same on a different spreadsheet?

Thanks in advance - Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `openbyID` to change data on other sheet from your current sheet, the ID here is refer to the unique combination of text & number from the sheet URL:

```
function clear() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx') 
      spreadsheet.getRange('Responses!C8:E50').setValue('');
}
```

Comment: That did it!  Once I figured out the text & number from the sheet URL and not the total URL it worked.  Thank you so much....

Comment: You can use the complete url by using `openbyUrl` or the sheet id itself with `openbyId`, both method work. Glad you find it useful :)